# Excel VBA to check autofilter for data

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I need help checking for autofiltered rows not including the header. I want it to give a message box "No records found." then exit sub or continue with copy paste if there are rows beyond the header row. I know I need an If/Else entry after the filter to check for data but I'm having trouble figuring how to check. This code is being done from a UserForm button I created.

Here is my script:

```
Private Sub Searchbycompanyfield_Click()

If CompanyComboBox1.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please enter a Company to begin search."
    Exit Sub
End If
ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$H").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=EQDataEntry.CompanyComboBox1.Value, Operator:=xlOr
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("A5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Call MessageBoxYesOrNoMsgBox
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wow! That was fast responses. Thanks for the info Philip, Chris and Nutsch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See below, SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) will allow you to return a rng object of the filtered cells. You just need to check the number of rows in this for your condition:

```
Private Sub Searchbycompanyfield_Click()

    If CompanyComboBox1.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter a Company to begin search."
    Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    Set sh = ActiveSheet

    sh.AutoFilterMode = False
    sh.Range("$A:$H").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=EQDataEntry.CompanyComboBox1.Value, Operator:=xlOr

    Set rng = sh.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    If (rng.Rows.Count > 1) Then

        rng.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").[A5]

        Call MessageBoxYesOrNoMsgBox

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I used something close to this. I'll post it in case anyone else needs  it.

Answer (score 3):

count the lines, or check if the last row is the header

```
if application.worksheetfunction.subtotal(3,activesheet.columns(1))>1 then 
    msgbox "Records"
else
    msgbox "No Records"
end if
```

check the last row

```
if activesheet.cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row>1 then 
    msgbox "Records"
else
    msgbox "No Records"
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your maco refactored to demo a method of using the filter range.  Also removes the need to `Select` ranges

```
Sub Searchbycompanyfield()

    If CompanyComboBox1.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter a Company to begin search."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    ' clear any existing autofilter
    sh.AutoFilterMode = False
    sh.Range("$A:$H").AutoFilter Field:=1, _
        Criteria1:=EQDataEntry.CompanyComboBox1.Value, Operator:=xlOr

    Set rng = sh.AutoFilter.Range
    ' Check if there is any data in filter range
    If rng.Rows.Count > 1 Then
        Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1)
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rng = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        If Err.Number = 1004 Then
            ' No cells returned by filter
            Exit Sub
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        rng.Copy ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").[A5]

    End If
    ' remove filter
    sh.AutoFilterMode = False
    MessageBoxYesOrNoMsgBox

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else needing this, I ended up using:

`Private Sub Searchbycompanyfield_Click()`

```
If CompanyComboBox1.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please enter a Company to begin search."
Exit Sub
End If

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

Set sh = ActiveSheet

sh.AutoFilterMode = False
sh.Range("$A:$H").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=EQDataEntry.CompanyComboBox1.Value, Operator:=xlOr

Set rng = sh.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

If (rng.Rows.Count > 1) Then

    rng.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").[A5]
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Call MessageBoxYesOrNoMsgBox

Else
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.Cells.AutoFilter
MsgBox "No records found."
Exit Sub
End If
```

End Sub

Thanks again for your helps guys.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this. Try this solution.

```
Dim count As Long
count = Application.WorksheetFunction.count(rng_SmPrt.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
```

This one returns the no of visible rows correctly.