# AutoFilter without On Error Resume Next

Tags: excel, excel-2010, autofilter, vba

I have two tables on separate sheets, I'm iterating through one table to do some processing on another table.

```
Dim shPoints As Worksheet
Dim shEmployees As Worksheet
Dim rngPoints As Range 
Dim rngEmployee As Range

Dim strEUID as String ' Stores the Employee ID
Dim intRow as Integer ' Current row

Set shEmployees = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Employees")
Set rngEmployee = shEmployees.Range("tblEmployees")
Set shPoints = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Points")
Set rngPoints = shPoints.Range("tblPoints")

shEmployee.AutoFilterMode = False
shPoints.AutoFilterMode = False

' On Error Resume Next  ' Works with this turned on
For intRow = 1 To shEmployee.Range("tblEmployees").Rows.Count
    strEUID = shEmployees.Range("tblEmployees[EUID]").Cells(intRow)

    rngPoints.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=strEUID
    ' The filter above produces empty results occasionally because some employees do not have any points.
    ' Next line error "No cells were found"
    If shPoints.Range("tblPoints").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count > 1 Then
        ' Do stuff
    End If

Next intRow
```

Have an employees table I'm going to iterate through to do some calculations to track employee occurrences for point system tracking.  If I throw in "On Error Resume Next" the code works for employees who actually have occurences.  For employees with a clean ticket the following line errors out saying "No cells were found."  I've found various solutions on the web, including one [on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12681474/excel-vba-to-check-autofilter-for-data) but none have worked.

Edit:  I've substituted a work around but would still really like to know if this "No cells were found" error can be handled without On Error Resume Next.  The work around is using a countif function that searches the Occurences table for the Employees ID in the Employees table, if the count is zero it skips it.

```
If shPoints.Application.CountIf(Range("tblPoints[EUID]"), strEUID) > 0 Then
    'Do Stuff
End If
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code setting up a value for `strEUID`, then your code is effectively `Criteria1:=""`

Comment: Thanks PatricK, I'll add that in in a few.  I've honestly snipped out a lot of "noise" that I don't think would help solve the problem.  strEUID is setup on each iteration of the employees table.

Comment: Try `Set rng = shPoints.Range("tblPoints").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` `If rng Is Nothing Then` `...` `Else` `...` `End If`

Comment: Agreed with @TonyDallimore, since if nothing is found, calling the `.Rows` method will error out. You should also `strEUID = shEmployees.Range("tblEmployees[EUID]").Cells(intRow).Value` even thou it is done in background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to *if this "No cells were found" error can be handled without On Error Resume Next.* is NO

That's just how SpecialCells works.

General form is

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim rFiltered As Range

    '...
    ' Other code
    '...

    Set rFiltered = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rFiltered = YourRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0 ' or use your own error handler
    If Not rFiltered Is Nothing Then
        ' Process filtered list
    End If

    '...
    ' Other code
    '...

End Sub
```